# Detached Head while checking out remote branch

Tags: git, github

I have a directory containing some files. I initialized it as a git repository using

```
git init
```

I added the current files and committed them to empty repository using

```
git add .
git commit -m <Message>
```

Now i added the remote named origin

```
git remote add origin <remote url>
```

At this point, i remembered that my remote repository already had some code and hence it would have been better to merge them. So i checked out another branch with current code as

```
git checkout development
```

Now i *intended to pull remote code in my master and then merge development branch (containing local code) into the master.* However when i tried doing

```
git checkout origin/master
```

in my master branch then i got a message that HEAD is detached. I am not sure how did this happen.

It would be great if someone could explain why did this happen.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Yes this is explained in that answer. I got the workaround but i am little confused. If i am checking out the remote branch then should all the local changes be overridden with remote content ? If so then my head pointing at origin/master commit would be the correct one.

Comment: After you've checked out the remote branch, your working tree reflects the commit that `origin/master` points to, yes. However, `HEAD` then points to the commit that `origin/master` points to. `HEAD` cannot point to a remote-tracking branch; only to a normal branch, or to a commit directly. In the latter case, you're in detached-HEAD state.

Comment: You explained this very beautifully. I think this bit was missing in the other answer. Thanks !

Comment: I'll add the missing bit to the other answer.